# Alert in JavaScript called in mousedown event listener prevents a radio button to become checked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Given the following code:

```
var inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e)
        {
            alert(1);
            console.log(this.checked); // this.checked is always false here
            
            if (!this.checked) {
                some_code();
            }
        });
    }
```

Is it ok that `alert()` prevents a radio button to become active? It works as expected without it.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/9UGZM/

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You might consider adding a link to a site where you are able to reproduce the error - one easy way of doing so is using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so we can see what's the specific issue going on.

Comment: Why do you want alert there?

Comment: The code was simplified before being published. There is actually an AJAX call inside mousedown event.

Comment: So does the same thing happen without the alert? (And on what browser? Because my Opera does check the radio button in your fiddle.) Are you preventing the default action of the event by any chance?

Comment: Default action is not being prevented. I have checked the behaviour in Chrome 31 and IE11. Taking alert() away solves the problem, but I would like to find out why it happens at all

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this behaviour becuase you've bound the `mousedown` event. The checkbox doesn't change state until there is a `mouseup` or `click` event.

The `mouseup` and `click` events don't happen because of the `alert`. Remove it and you're good, or bound to `click` or `mouseup` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click` event for perfect output. also `return` your function try this

```
var inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e)
        {
            console.log(this.checked); // this.checked is always false here

            if (!this.checked) {
                some_code();
            }
          return;
        });
    }
```

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9UGZM/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: This seems more like a bug if anything. `return;` should be the same as not returning anything at all, and the function can't return yet because of the `alert`. Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the option. The point is just to prevent a radio button from being checked depending on AJAX response.

Comment: earlier `mousedown` event was getting stopped by `alert` message. Also after removing `alert`, console was showing `false` as value because it was not checked till the function complete execution. in second click it was showing `True`. So, `click` event is better option in such situation.